# Getting fatal: protocol error: expected old/new/ref when trying to git clone

Tags: git

I'm having a weird problem with my Git repo. Cloning the repo on *my machine* works just fine, but my co-worker can't clone the repo on his machine. Here's the deal:

My user, on my Mac OS X machine: works just fine

My user, same exact command, on my co-worker's Arch Linux machine: doesn't work

So everything is the exact same except the machine. The error we get is this:

> fatal: protocol error: expected old/new/ref, got 'want
>   db29ccc950e5b89bfa9084768de3b9c0feeb3494 side-band-64k ofs-delta'
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Any ideas why this might be happening?

**Edit**:

Command:

```
git clone -u /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/bin/git-upload-pack \
  ssh://myuser@mysite.com/var/git/myrepo.git
```

Place where repo is:

```
ssh://myuser@mysite.com/var/git/myrepo.git
```

My Git version: 1.7.5

Co-worker's Git version: 1.8.0

Comment: What's the exact command you're running? What is the repository URL?  What version of `git` are you running? What version of `git` is your friend working?

Comment: And the version of `git` installed on `mysite.com`?

Comment: We're running 1.7.9 on mysite.com.

Comment: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Fwd-Remote-hung-up-during-git-fetch-td7571702.html has some interesting suggestion: What a  `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone ...` would return?